Woocommerce product filters based on data from the specifications table
I need a little help setting up Woocommerce product filters based on data from the specifications table. I use two plugins.

Product Table Specification For Woocommerce (https://woocommerce.com/document/product-specification-table-for-woocommerce/)
Filter Everything (https://wordpress.org/plugins/filter-everything/)

I have a specifications table for products e.g. Headphones.
Attributes and several values ​​are created. I need to create filters based on this data. Unfortunately, I have been struggling with this for some time and I can't cope with it, the authors of the table plugin sent me to read the meta key: meta _pst_product_specification_table_rules and use it to find the attribute metadata, but I can't achieve it
I tried using different values ​​like pst_attr_field_values_40775, but that didn't work properly either.
